# Regex to validate integer

Tags: java

Need regular expression for format where maximum 7 digits are allowed, with comma after every third digit.

Valid values are:

```
7
 77
 555
 1,234
12,345
444,888
4,669,988
```

Currently I am using `([0-9]{1}(,?[0-9]{3}){1,2}` which fails in first three scenarios.

Comment: Do you have to use a regex for it? DecimalFormat would be a much more straight forward choice.

Comment: Parse the number and make sure it is less than 10^8.

Answer (score 2):

Use this one:

```
[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3}){0,2}
```

To validate an integer from string (you have to remove ,):

```
try {
  Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll(",","");
  //valid integer
} catch (Exception e) {
  //not valid integer
}
```

Comment: It also accepts "111,123,446" and "11,123,446".But limit is 7.

Comment: I need to validate with comma to check proper comma position  and limit characters max length to 7.

Answer (score 2):

try this regex

```
"\\d{1,3}|\\d{1,3},\\d{3}|\\d{1,2},\\d{3},\\d{3}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\d{1,3}(,\d{3}){0,2}
```

Try this regex along with number validation for a length check.

```
public boolean isNumValid(String num) throws ParseException {
    if (!(NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(num).intValue() > 9999999)) {
        if (num.matches("\\d{1,3}(,\\d{3}){0,2}")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```